# WMS Download Request

Tags: qgis, wms

I'm downloading more than 700 tiled SHP from this site:
"http://www502.regione.toscana.it/geoscopio/cartoteca.html#"
It is possible to download automatically all tiles from QGIS or ARCGIS? 
[image]

The site provide also a qgis an interactive qgis project, like this:

[image]

This is wms link:
http://www502.regione.toscana.it/wmsraster/com.rt.wms.RTmap/wms?map=wmscartoteca&map_resolution=91&

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The difficult part is extracting sequence that's added after the sheet number. An non-programming way would be to click through all the map footprints to copy all the links.

After you turn on the CARG Geologia and click on a sheet you issue a request like this:

```
http://www502.regione.toscana.it/wmsraster/com.rt.wms.RTmap/wms?map=wmscartoteca&SERVICE=WMS&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=rt_cartoteca.geologia.carg&QUERY_LAYERS=rt_cartoteca.geologia.carg&STYLES=&FEATURE_COUNT=50&HEIGHT=418&WIDTH=1142&SRS=EPSG:25832&VERSION=1.1.1&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&X=422&Y=72&BBOX=328175.86671069%2C4733238.585752%2C965689.22964951%2C4965467.6216386&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&IDTPN=216100&codTPN=-9301065
```

IDTPN=216100 is your sheet number.

You can calculate X,Y,BBOX and IDTPN and then run a simple python script (I'd go with Python/BeautifulSoup) which will send requests and parse the anwsers to extract links like this:

http://www502.regione.toscana.it/geoscopio/download/geologia/carg_toscana/vett/v_216100_1fe8b28d20c60d8ec8ba744f2f4e1f96.zip